# Data from the JSON array in Java

Tags: java, json

I've this JSON data and after a long work I could not find a way out to get the result. My aim is to get the value of the **video_url** even it is null but yes I've put up a check in order to check whether something is coming or not. I've tried every possible way but all I'm getting is no output.

Here is my code:

```
{
"data":
    [
        {
            "type":"project-users",
            "id":"1",
            "attributes":
                   {
                    "video-url":null
                    },
            "links":
                {
                    "self": "http://localhost:3000/api/project-users/1"
                }
        },

        {   
            "type":"project-users",
            "id":"2",
            "attributes":
                {
                "video-url":null
                },
            "links":
                {
                "self":"http://localhost:3000/api/project-users/2"
                }
        },

        {
            "type":"project-users",
            "id":"3",
            "attributes":
                {
                "video-url":null
                },
            "links":
                {"self":"http://localhost:3000/api/project-users/3"
                }
        }

    ] }
```

In order to get the value of **video_url from the attribute object I did that** but failed :

```
private void jSONLoadData(String response) throws JSONException{

    //talk about this in getting the video url
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");

    for(int i=0; i<jArray.length() ; i++){
        JSONObject jsonObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String url = jsonObj.getJSONObject("attributes").getString("video_url");
        Log.e("URL", url);

        if(url.equals(null) || url.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: response is nothing but the above JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of calling `getString("video_url");` first check whether `video_url` is null (i.e. `isNull("video_url")`) or not.

Please try using below code.

```
private void jSONLoadData(String response) throws JSONException{

    //talk about this in getting the video url
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");

    for(int i=0; i<jArray.length() ; i++){
        JSONObject jsonObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        boolean isURLNull = jsonObj.getJSONObject("attributes").isNull("video_url");
        String url="";
        if(!isURLNull){
            url = jsonObj.getJSONObject("attributes").getString("video_url");
        }
        if(isURLNull || url.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done this thing earlier also and I was getting the desired result, the difference was that there **video_url was this : ""** and now it has null in the json data and I spent two hours searching or it. This machine stuffs. Thanks  alot brother.